# How the KMP changes MP tables?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

when I study the algorithms for string matching, I met the lecture notes says that for example the pattern is `abaab`, the Morris-Pratt table is:

```
| a | b | a | a | b |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
```

I understand how this is generated but the KMP table given is:

```
| a | b | a | a | b |
| 0 | -1| 1 | 0 | 2 |
```

Can anyone help me understand why the 2nd table is like that?
Thanks/